# What is the idiomatic way to encode an iterator with serde_json?

Tags: json, rust, encode, serde

I'm trying to `drain()` a `vec` in Rust and encode the results as a JSON string. What's the best, idiomatic way to do this?

```
#![feature(custom_derive, plugin)]
#![plugin(serde_macros)]

extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point {
        Point {
            x: x,
            y: y
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut points = vec![Point::new(1,2), Point::new(-2,-1), Point::new(0, 0)];
    let mut drain = points.drain(..);

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&drain).unwrap());
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with serializing and then draining?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Draining iterators are an interesting beast. They allow you to chunk out a part of a collection, taking ownership of some but not necessarily all of the items in the collection. They also allow you to do this in a reasonably efficient manner. For example, a vector could move the trailing data *en masse* with a single `memcpy`.

However, serde doesn't natively support serializing iterators (for a good reason, keep reading). You can look at the the [`Serialize` trait](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.101/serde/trait.Serialize.html) to see the types of things it supports.

You'd have to implement this yourself:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.101
use std::{cell::RefCell, vec};

struct DrainIteratorAdapter<'a, T>(RefCell<vec::Drain<'a, T>>);

impl<'a, T: 'a> serde::Serialize for DrainIteratorAdapter<'a, T>
where
    T: serde::Serialize,
{
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        serializer.collect_seq(self.0.borrow_mut().by_ref())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut points = vec![Point::new(1, 2), Point::new(-2, -1), Point::new(0, 0)];
    let adapter = DrainIteratorAdapter(RefCell::new(points.drain(..)));

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&adapter).unwrap());
}
```

The core hard part is that serialization is supposed to not have any side-effects. This is a very reasonable decision. However, whenever you call `next` on an iterator, you have to mutate it in order to update the state. To combine these two mismatched concepts, we have to use something like a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html).

Beyond that, it's just a matter of implementing the [`serde::Serialize` trait](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.101/serde/trait.Serialize.html). Since we own neither `serde::Serialize` or `vec::Drain`, we have to create a *newtype* to place the implementation on.

We can generalize this solution to apply to any iterator. This happens to make it read a bit nicer, in my opinion:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.101
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct IteratorAdapter<I>(RefCell<I>);

impl<I> IteratorAdapter<I> {
    fn new(iterator: I) -> Self {
        Self(RefCell::new(iterator))
    }
}

impl<I> serde::Serialize for IteratorAdapter<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: serde::Serialize,
{
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        serializer.collect_seq(self.0.borrow_mut().by_ref())
    }
}
```

What's the downside to this solution? **Serializing the same value twice has different results!** If we simply serialize and print the value twice, we get:

```
[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":-2,"y":-1},{"x":0,"y":0}]
[]
```

This is because iterators are transient beasts - once they have read one value, it's gone! This is a nice trap waiting for you to fall into it.

---

In your example, none of this really makes sense. You have access to the entire `Vec`, so you might as well serialize it (or a slice of it) at that point. Additionally, there's no reason (right now) to `drain` the entire collection. That would be equivalent to just calling `into_iter`.